# Why can root see a dir but not a user?

Tags: git, centos, vps

I created a git repo on my vps through root and made it shared so a group of people have the ability to access it:

```
# mkdir example.git
# cd example.git
# git init --bare --shared=group
Initialized empty shared Git repository in /root/example.git/
# ls
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
# chgrp -R devs .
```

Then as a user on my local pc I created a dir and added example.git as the new origin for this git repo. Finally I tried to to make a push to origin:

```
mkdir bubbles && cd bubbles
bubbles ranuka$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ranuka/Desktop/bubbles/.git/
bubbles ranuka$ ls
bubbles ranuka$ git remote add origin ranuka@000.000.000.000:example.git
bubbles ranuka$ echo "Hello" > readme.txt
bubbles ranuka$ git add readme.txt
bubbles ranuka$ git commit -m "Adding a readme file"
[master (root-commit) 2c89e43] Adding a readme file
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 100644 readme.txt
bubbles ranuka$ git push origin master
ranuka@000.000.000.000's password: 
fatal: 'example.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

Confounded by this error since I know example.git is clearly a repo on my vps. I logged in on my vps as 'ranuka' and tried to cd to example.git yet couldn't, but for some reason I could as root.. What gives?

My goal was to create a git repo on my vps that a bunch of users in a certain group could access and make push/pulls to.

After running ls -a on root@000.000.000.000 and ranuka@000.000.000.000
These were the results:

```
.                             example.git
..                            gitosis
ajenti-repo-1.0-1.noarch.rpm  install.log
anaconda-ks.cfg               install.log.syslog
.bash_history                 pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm
.bash_logout                  .pki
.bash_profile                 repo.git
.bashrc                       .rnd
.cshrc                        .ssh
epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm   .tcshrc
```

AND

```
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc
```

So it seems as if root and ranuka are located on different directories with no relationship whatsoever.

Seems like I'll have to create a symlink..

Comment: Of course they're different. You're ussing SSH paths, `user@host:path`. Since you've got two different usernames (`root` and `ranuka`), you're dealing with two entirely different accounts on the host.

Comment: Can you do `ls -la` to show the permissions and ownership of the files?

Comment: @MarcB ding ding winnar! Is a syslink the only way to resolve this or is there a more graceful way? @ HeatfanJohn I don't think ownerships would matter since I set example.git to be shared

Comment: You can use an absolute path, instead of relative-to-user-home-dir, e.g. `root@0.0.0.0:/path/to/repo`. As long as it's absolute path, and the account you're using has rights to the files/dirs, no symlink necessary.

Comment: Ok I figured that out and created a symlink sudo ln -s /root/example.git /home/ranuka/ and set the origin to ranuka@0.0.0.0:example.git yet it still gives me the same error fatal: 'example.git' does not appear to be a git repository

Comment: Your `ranuka` user almost certainly doesn't have permissions on the `/root` directory itself to even be able to see the `example.git` directory. Why are you not just creating this repository as the user you want to use it as?

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried this but I still run into the same error... I set a sym link ln -s /home/foo/example.git /home/ranuka/ . Both users are in the same group so I don't see why it would be a permission problem.

Comment: In order for that link to work the user still needs to be able to get access to the `example.git` directory itself which resides in a directory `/root` to which they likely do not have access. You can't get around this with a symlink. Your user needs at least execute permissions on the `/root` directory for this to work I believe. What permissions does `/root` have?

Comment: The user foo isn't on the root directory but in its own home directory. I deleted the original example.git on the root directory and init a new one in the home directory of foo.